# Creating a thread which writes into a file

Tags: c, linux

I am learning threads and trying to implement a code which creates a thread. The thread writes into a file. If the thread has been created it `returns 0` . The code here `returns 0` but it does go into the function `write()` but does not writes in the file . Just to check it goes in the function i have put a `printf()` statement.I want the input should be taken by command line here but it also does not work so to make it simpler  i have written only "hello world" to the file  .

Here is the code :-

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void *write(void *arg)
{

    printf("HI \n");
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "a");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("error\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(fp, "hello world");
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int tid;
    tid = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, write, NULL);
    printf("thread1 return %d \n", tid);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect what's happening is the exit() call is executing before the fprintf() gets to the point of putting content into the buffer.

pthread_create() returns after *creating* the thread, not after the thread finishes, and then both threads run simultaneously.  Maybe this is your first "race condition"?

`void *result; pthread_join(tid, &result);` will wait for the function running in the other thread to return (and get it's return value).

**correction**
Forgot that the file pointer is not automatically closed, so this will thwart you as well.  Call fflush() or fclose() after the fprintf.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join with the thread to wait for it to finish before exiting your main program.

```
  tid=pthread_create(&thread,NULL,write,NULL);
  printf("thread1 return %d \n",tid);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  exit(0);
```

Your thread function should return a value since it is declared to do so. Returning NULL is fine.

Comment: oh yes i missed this point and what if we have mutiple threads working on a same buffer one at a time?

Comment: very bad things happen.  The output into the buffer gets corrupted, and it's possible (likely?) to end up with seg faults as FILE * variables are not thread-safe.

Comment: @user2532621: This is true, but protection of critical section is a different problem, and not one presented in this question.

Comment: sounds like a good case for sticking with standard file I/O (i.e. using open() and write()).  Just make sure all content written by each thread is output in a single write if that's the route taken.

Comment: ok i got it that pthread_join waits to finish but what if we wanted to assign pthread_mutex so that only one thread could access the same buffer ,how do we do that?

Comment: You make the mutex global, or you pass it in as the argument to your thread function in the last argument of `pthread_create()`.

Comment: oh okay i am trying :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoudl this code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void write(string filename)
{
ofstream outfile(filename);

outfile<<"Hello World!"<<endl;

outfile.close();
}
int main()
{
thread t(write, "file.txt");
t.join();
}
```

use this command to compile the code:`g++ -g -std=c++11 test.cpp -lpthread`

Comment: This isn't C, but C++, which is a differnt language.

Comment: yeah, why not use C++, the C+11 is very strong, it has very useful features.

Comment: I do not want to disagree on C++ being strong. But because the question is tagged C, a solution in C++ is not an answer.